# Установил Composer, один раз запустил, при повторном запуске -bash: composer: command not found

Tags: laravel, composer

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь самостоятельно разобраться с установкой Laravel через Composer. Сервер - амазоновский инстанс (Centos 7, NGINX+PHP-FPM, PHP 7.1).

Не уверен, что верно выбрал место для установки Composer, но ставлю в /var/www, доступная из веб папка находится тут /var/www/html.

Устанавливаю Composer согласно https://getcomposer.org/download/ (Command-line installation).

Вроде бы все ок http://prntscr.com/h54y73

Ввожу команду: # php composer.phar результат http://prntscr.com/h54yrj

Пытаюсь создать новый проект командой: # composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
(отсюда https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation)

Выводится сообщение: 
bash: composer: command not found

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `php composer.phar` и `composer` - это совершенно разные вызовы

Answer (score 0):

Установи composer глобально.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/116960/global-installation-of-composer-manual

Answer (score 0):

> отсюда https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation

Новый проект создался командой:

**php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog**

вместо:

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog